# Code fails one input test

Tags: php

I am solving a paper for Canadian Computing Contest (CCC) and come across a question for which I wrote this code. The question is question 2.

http://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/computing/2010/stage1/juniorEn.pdf

The problem is that I couldn't understand why one of the five tests is failing. I would had solved it myself but couldn't since I don't know the input for which the output is wrong.

Please I searched a lot for this and couldn't find a solution. Any help would seriously be appreciated!

```
<?php
    $a = (int)fgets(STDIN);
    $b = (int)fgets(STDIN);
    $c = (int)fgets(STDIN);
    $d = (int)fgets(STDIN);
    $s = (int)fgets(STDIN);

    $nCycles = intval(floor($s / ($a + $b)));
    $bCycles = intval(floor($s / ($c + $d))); 
    //$nEnd = $bEnd = false;

    // checking distance moved by nickky and byron
    $nSteps = (($a - $b) * $nCycles) + ($s % ($a + $b));
    $bSteps = (($c - $d) * $bCycles) + ($s % ($c + $d));

    if ($bSteps > $nSteps) {echo "Byron";}  
    elseif ($nSteps > $bSteps) {echo "Nikky";}  
    else {echo "Tied";}  
?>
```

Comment: Provide the values of `$a, $b, $c, $d, $s`.

Comment: And expected output.

Comment: The online grader doesn't specify the input with which it is checking. That's is the problem.

Comment: But you can check for $a = 100, $b = 100, $c = 100, $d = 100, $s = 10000.

Comment: Cant you look by doing `print_r(compact('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 's'))`?

Comment: What would this function do?